# Nonlinear ODE involving trigonometric terms

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

I need to solve the following ODE:

$$y'+A\sin(2y)+B\sin(y)+C\cos(y)+D=0$$

I want to find y' (explicit/unexplicit)  rather than y.

I tryied to use the Weierstrass transform, after substituting the terms of the transformation [$\cos(y)=(1-z^2)/(1+z^2)$  ; $\sin(y)=2z/(1+z^2)$ ; $y'=2z'/(1+z^2)$ ; $\sin(2y)=2\sin(y)\cos(y)$] I got this eqn:
$$z'=1/(a*z^4+b*z^3+c*z^2+d*z+e)$$  where a,b,..,e are functions of the scalars A,B,C,D I tried to solve it in a web calculator, and it does give a [really long solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%201%2F%28a*z%5E4%2Bb*z%5E3%2Bc*z%5E2%2Bd*z%2Be%29) and then when substituting back z= tan(y/2) I couldn't extract y and derivate it to find y'.

It's is not mandatory to use the Weierstrass transform, I used it because it worked for me when I try to solve the easier case when $B=C=0$.

Thanks to anyone who devotes his time to this question.

Regards, Daniel.

Comment: Warstrauss? You mean Weierstrass? Could you please share some more details of what you tried, it's not clear.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake I will edit:)

Comment: Sometimes you only end with an implicit solution.